# IBM Worklight - How to stop calling WL.Client.Invoke Procedure from android Mobile WebView

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We have tested worklight android-application in console preview and also in Android Mobile WebView using chrome Devtools. After deploying it on Production we do not want to entertain any android client to send any invoke adapter request from Mobile WebView to WL production server?

How can we stop this do we need to change some configuration on production, like disable debug mode or something ?
Please advice.

Comment: Something tells me that you and eshaa are on the same team (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798177/unauthorized-wl-client-invokeprocedure-call)? Both of you are asking the same question. Both of you are not fully explaining the scenario. Explain it in greater detail and reproduction steps.

Comment: What do you mean "android mobile webview"? Do you mean the browser app in your android device? Provide exact steps that reproduce the so-called "unwanted behavior".

Answer (score 0):

I think the test is a bit misleading since "you" as an attacker will have several prerequisites: have the technical skill of manipulate code, invoking code and know what is a "normal" user.

That said:

1. In the upcoming MobileFirst Platform v7.0 you will be able to obfuscate the code of a mobile app (iOS, Android and so on). You can also [do this manually](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en) now.
2. Already now you can enable the [Application Authenticity Protection](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/) feature as well as the webResourcesChecksumTest and webResourcesEncryption features. See the *security element* section in the [Application Descriptor user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html).

   The above will add several layers of protection to your application, either preventing tampering with the application code, not allowing to use the app if its checksum has change and verify the application identity.